# Java isSorted cannot be resolved or is not a field error when calling a method within the class

Tags: java

Error in line 17 outputs: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    isSorted cannot be resolved or is not a field at Found.find(Found.java:17) at Found.main(Found.java:4)

I'm fairly new to java, and I can't understand why I'm getting this error.

```
public class Found {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NotFoundException {
    int x = 5 + find(7, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }); // whoops!

    find(7, new int[] { });
}

/**
 * Find a value x in an array a.
 * @param x value to search for
 * @param a array to search; requires a sorted
 *          (a[0] <= a[1] <= ... a[a.length-1])
 * @return returns lowest i s.t. a[i] == x, or -1 if x is not in a
 */
public static int find(int x, int[] a) {
    assert a.isSorted: // remember to turn on assertions with -ea
    findBinaryFirstInRange(x, a, 0, a.length);
}

public static boolean isSorted(int[] a) {
    for (int ii = 1; ii < a.length; ii++) {
        if (a[ii] < a[ii-1]) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}

public static int findLinear(int x, int[] a) {
    for (int ii = 0; ii < a.length; ii++) {
        if (x == a[ii]) {
            return ii;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// returns lowest i s.t. ...
public static int findBinaryFirstInRange(int x, int[] a, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) { return -1; }

    int middle = (start + end) / 2;

    if (x < a[middle]) {
        return findBinaryFirstInRange(x, a, start, middle);
    } else if (x > a[middle]) {
        return findBinaryFirstInRange(x, a, middle + 1, end);
    } else if (middle > 0 && a[middle-1] == x) {
        return findBinaryFirstInRange(x, a, start, middle);
    } else {
        return middle;
    }
}

// returns some i s.t. ...
public static int findBinaryInRange(int x, int[] a, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) { return -1; }

    int middle = (start + end) / 2;

    if (x < a[middle]) {
        return findBinaryInRange(x, a, start, middle);
    } else if (x > a[middle]) {
        return findBinaryInRange(x, a, middle + 1, end);
    } else {
        return middle;
    }
} }
class NotFoundException extends Exception { }
```

Comment: `assert a.isSorted:` - so what do you think you are doing with this code?

Comment: `assert isSorted(a);`

Answer (score 0):

Use: `assert isSorted(a);` to make sure that the integer array `a` is sorted by your `isSorted` function.

Comment: This will not solve OP's problem..isSorted function is written by OP

Comment: 1) The `isSorted()` method is already defined in OP's code. 2) Your assert statement will not compile.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to check his statement. my bad!

Comment: There are still two errors in your assert statement. Also, in Java they're called methods, not functions. And: `a` is not a list, it's an array.

Comment: I didn't scroll through the rest of user8677895's code, so I didn't see his isSorted function. I assumed that it was because of his function, not his assert. My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

This mean that you ran some code that has compilation errors in it.  That is a bad idea.  Fix your compilation errors **before** you run your code.

I presume you are using Eclipse as that is (AFAIK) the only IDE that has the misfeature that allows you to launch code with compilation errors.  You should turn this off.  It is a bad idea.

- Go to "Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching" and set "Continue launch if project contains errors" to "Prompt".  (Unfortunately, you can't entirely disable it ....)

---

Now to the compilation error.  If you look in the code window for the class, you should see this line highlighted as a compilation error.

```
    assert a.isSorted: // remember to turn on assertions with -ea
```

and the compilation error should say "isSorted cannot be resolved or is not a field".

It is telling you the truth.  The variable `a` is declared with type `int[]`, and there is no field called `isSorted` for arrays.  (The *only* field defined for arrays is `length`.)

You have declared an isSorted **method** in the current class, but methods need to be called.  In this case you should do this:

```
    assert Found.isSorted(a);
```

because 1) it is declared to be a `static` method, and 2) it is declared to take a parameter.